# Anyone know what this capacitor is for in a BJT audio amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio, bjt, amplitude-modulation

I'm wondering what C46 is for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C46 is small. It limits open loop high frequency response .If omitted you could get instability. Sometimes this cap is called a compensation cap .Most IC opamps have this done internally.

Comment: That makes sense, looks like this is a miller compensation capacitor then, correct?  Is the placement also similar to a bootstrap capacitor for audio amplifiers or are they completely different.    Here is what I'm referring to: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/bootstrap-amplifier-circuit-using-transistors 
https://www.edaboard.com/threads/can-anyone-explain-me-bootstrapping-with-an-example.237660/